# Is the quartic diophantine equation $a^4+nb^4 = c^4+nd^4$ solvable for any integer $n$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

In 1995, Choudhry wrote the [paper](http://www.new1.dli.ernet.in/data1/upload/insa/INSA_2/20005a1b_1057.pdf) "On the Diophantine equation $A^4+nB^4 = C^4+nD^4$" and solved it for $75$ $n$ in the range $1\leq n\leq 101$. I thought the missing $n$ were either unsolvable or would have large solutions, but decided to have a crack at it anyway with a simple Mathematica search.

To my surprise, ALL $n$ in the range had solutions and were of relatively small size. See the complete table [here](http://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/0021e).

So here's the question (also asked by others prior):

> "Is $a^4+nb^4 = c^4+nd^4$ solvable in non-trivial integers (that is $a^4\neq c^4$) for any integer $n$?"

---

***Edit 1*** (a day later)

I just learned that Seiji Tomita has a [table](http://www3.alpha-net.ne.jp/users/fermat/dioph121e.html) for all $n<1000$. Only $n=\color{blue}{967}$ is missing.

***Edit 2*** (a week later)

Andrew Bremner finally found a "small" solution as,
$$416776^4-252386^4=\color{blue}{967}(98431^4-90427^4)$$ 
thus completing the table for $n<1000$. (It is not known if this is the smallest soln and Elkies has searched the range $a,c< 100000$).

***Edit 3*** (four years later)

It turns out there is a smaller one found by Oleg567,
$$251477^4 - 146927^4 =  \color{blue}{967}(44086^4 - 18748^4)$$
See his answer below for details on $n<5000$.

Comment: it would appear you take "solvable' to mean "there is at least one solution in non-negative integers with $a \neq c$"

Comment: Alright, it appears Choudhry did not have an electronic computer available, he used "ad hoc" methods which suggests hand calculations by laborious and varying means. Also he conjectures your questio in his final sentence, just before the references.

Comment: Obviously false for $n=0$, but I assume you want to exclude that case.

Comment: Oh, the reason I ask it that i would not know how to find ALL solutions for a fixed $n$

Comment: @aschepler: If $n=0$, then the only solution is $a^4=c^4$ which is specifically excluded by the question in the post body.

Comment: @WillJagy: Choudhry and I correspond now and then, and I just asked him why he missed small solutions. (I figured he did not use a computer for his search.)

Comment: @WillJagy: Also, for a fixed $n$ and given an initial rational point, the equation can be transformed to an elliptic curve. (Just like how Euler did for $n = 1$.) Thus, all solutions for a fixed $n$ should be generated by that curve.

Comment: alright. Choudhry never says he is restricting to only positive $h$ except for a hint in the abstract and again in the final sentence...probably best to consider your $n<0$ as a separate question; the behavior is very different

Comment: @Will, it's the same. If $n<0$, then $a^4-nb^4 = c^4-nd^4$ is equivalent to $a^4+nd^4 = c^4+nb^4$, eh?

Comment: Oh, good. Then we can just keep $n>0,$ as i edited in. That makes the whole thing far more plausible to me; given an $a,b$ you like, you get infinitely many chances, with  $x^2 - n y^2 = a^4 - n b^4,$ to get $x,y$ turn out to be both squares.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: which of numbers $n>1000$ still have unknown "decomposition" to $\dfrac{a^4-c^4}{d^4-b^4}$? There are numbers $1198, 1787, 1987, ...$ in this paper(https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.02602.pdf), but I don't know whether it is actual info or no.

Comment: @Oleg567: Hm, I'm mentioned in that paper. The authors acknowledge the contribution of Allan MacLeod whose work I'm familiar with. Assuming they did their computer search efficiently, and their elliptic curve calculations correctly, then it seems they have narrowed unknown $n<5000$ to a small list.

Comment: Simply I focused on this problem, and found (if my calculations are correct ) that there exists (the) smallest solutions for $n=967$: $$251477^4 - 146927^4 = 967(44086^4 - 18748^4),$$ and the smallest solutions for "hard cases" $n=1198, 1787, 1987, 2459$ are:
$$n=1198: 177233^4 - 134247^4 = 1198(35951^4 - 32517^4),$$
$$n=1787: 110571^4 - 78851^4 = 1787(16357^4 - 9891^4),$$
$$n=1987: 182489^4 - 4289^4 = 1987(27333^4 - 867^4),$$
$$n=2459: 213308^4 - 194886^4=2459(22479^4 - 2587^4).$$
And I wonder if it is new result or no.

Comment: @Oleg567: These results should be new. Elkies (who found the first $x^4+y^4+z^4=1$) searched $a^4-c^4 = 967(-b^4+d^4)$ only up to $a,c<100000$. Can you convert your comment into an answer? Also, kindly include a link to the paper and an updated list of unknown $n<5000$. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Mehdi_Baghalaghdam/publication/312194524_Is_the_quartic_Diophantine_equation_A4hB4C4hD4_solvable_for_any_integer_h/links/58ac53f3a6fdcc0e079e5553/Is-the-quartic-Diophantine-equation-A4-hB4C4-hD4-solvable-for-any-integer-h.pdf) (and https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.02602.pdf),

the integer solutions of this
equation (for that time) are known for all positive integer values of
$n \le 5000$ and $a,b,c,d \le 100\:000$, **except for** some numbers.

These exceptions $n$ are listed here:

$1198, 1787, 1987;$

$2459, 2572, 2711, 2797, 2971;$

$3086, 3193, 3307, 3319, 3334, 3347, 3571, 3622, 3623, 3628, 3644, 3646, 3742, 3814, 3818, 3851, 3868, 3907, 3943, 3980;$

$4003, 4006, 4007, 4051, 4054, 4099, 4231, 4252, 4358, 4406, 4414, 4418, 4478, 4519, 4574, 4583, 4630, 4643, 4684, 4870, 4955, 4999.$

---

*(Update)*

Great database of solution for this equation by **Seiji Tomita** contains solutions for **all** $n< 20000$. Thanks, **Sam** (follow link of his answer).

---

We'll use $2$ similar values (to estimate "size" of the solution):
$$
\mu_{\square}
 = \max\{a,b,c,d\};\tag{1}$$
$$
\mu_{\bigcirc}
 = \sqrt[4]{a^4+nb^4}.\tag{2}$$

Value $(1)$ was used mostly in current research; value $(2)$ was used in Seiji Tomita research.

---

Current results:

- the smallest (by $\mu_{\square}$ and $\mu_{\bigcirc}$) solutions were found for listed above values of $n$;
- for each $n\le 5000$ there exists at least one solution with $\mu_{\square}<620\:000$ and $\mu_{\bigcirc}<1\:100\:000$.

The table below contains the smallest solutions  for listed values.
And small improvement for value $n=967$.

\begin{array}{|r|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
n & (a,b,c,d) & \mu_{\bigcirc} & \mbox{by ...} & \mbox{notes} \\
\hline
967  & (251477, 18748, 146927, 44086) & \approx 253334 & & new \\
\hline
1198 & (177233, 32517, 134247, 35951) & \approx 219611 & & new \\
\hline
1787 & (110571, 9891, 78851, 16357) & \approx 113607 & & JW \\
\hline
1987 & (182489, 867, 4289, 27333) & \approx 182489 & & JW \\
\hline
2459 & (213308, 2587, 194886, 22479) & \approx 213311 & & JW \\
\hline
2572 & (308817, 54121, 271169, 56253) & \approx 420150 &\mu_{\square} & new \\
     & (394714, 20667, 286866, 51413) & \approx 396608 &\mu_{\bigcirc}& new \\
\hline
2711 & (270983, 20284, 200731, 35338) & \approx 276573 & & JW \\
\hline
2797 & (159689, 6263, 159577, 6841) & \approx 159953 & & new \\
\hline
2971 & (109288, 18485, 92740, 19339) & \approx 148746 & & JW  \\
\hline
3086 & (376829, 16357, 265733, 47263) & \approx 377857 & & ST + \\
\hline
3193 & (102997, 19519, 10091, 20609) & \approx 154920 &\mu_{\square} & maybe\;new \\
     & (125429, 11042, 437, 17434) & \approx 131053 &\mu_{\bigcirc} & ST +  \\
\hline
3307 & (337537, 27465, 251109, 42595) & \approx 349156 & & JW \\
\hline
3319 & (105539, 5039, 53773, 13727) & \approx 105991 & & JW \\
\hline
3334 & (202509, 8212, 189173, 18798) & \approx 202964 & & ST + \\
\hline
3347 & (225431, 2704, 158491, 27634) & \approx 225435 & & JW \\
\hline
3571 & (250803, 20129, 213427, 28833) & \approx 259617 & & JW \\
\hline
3622 & (565013, 110014, 347731, 114284)& \approx 891789 &\mu_{\square}& new \\
     & (843607, 64857, 217639, 111921) & \approx 869113 &\mu_{\bigcirc}& new \\
\hline
3623 & (138251, 29344, 71883, 30228) & \approx 235034 & & JW \\
\hline
3628 &  (617824, 57931, 106276, 84667) & \approx 657212 & & ST +  \\
\hline
3644 & (118519, 9823, 43639, 15809) & \approx 123315 & & new \\
\hline
3646 & (105497, 7993, 95033, 11191) & \approx 108532 & & new \\
\hline
3742 & (322387, 172226, 250139, 172316)& \approx 1.34813\times10^6 &\mu_{\square}& new \\
     & (1021473, 98254, 187193, 139968)& \approx 1.09496\times10^6 &\mu_{\bigcirc} & ST + \\
\hline
3814 & (96317, 7481, 6661, 12661) & \approx 99498.2 & & new, (small?) \\
\hline
3818 & (67219, 3637, 39021, 8373) & \approx 67762.3 & & new, (small?) \\
\hline
3851 & (108451, 2221, 22483, 13763) & \approx 108469 & & JW \\
\hline
3868 & (141656, 4633, 137788, 10327) & \approx 141812 & & new \\
\hline
3907 & (154274, 8879, 83948, 19291) & \approx 155901 & & JW \\
\hline
3943 & (109819, 20074, 54617, 21068) & \approx 167424 & & JW \\
\hline
3980 & (93077, 10904, 66411, 12948) & \approx 107048 & & ST +, (small?) \\
\hline
4003 & (156337, 137593, 115867, 137603)& \approx 1.09456\times10^6 &\mu_{\square} & new \\
     & (182563, 5887, 137677, 20849) & \approx 182760 &\mu_{\bigcirc} & JW \\
\hline
4006 & (142183, 67157, 22063, 67241) & \approx 534949 &\mu_{\square} & maybe\;new \\
     & (143746, 343, 71638, 17783) & \approx 143746 &\mu_{\bigcirc} & ST +  \\
\hline
4007 & (148131, 9592, 124089, 16234) & \approx 150674 & & JW \\
\hline
4051 & (368461, 137025, 11973, 137465) & \approx 1.09669\times10^6 &\mu_{\square} & new \\
     & (442912, 213, 410504, 39723) & \approx 442912 &\mu_{\bigcirc} & JW \\
\hline
4054 & (406147, 37967, 239933, 53137) & \approx 434477 & & new \\
\hline
4099 & (108466, 8549, 63692, 13687) & \approx 112522 & & JW + \\
\hline
4231 & (165485, 1073, 164533, 7975) & \approx 165485 & & JW + \\
\hline
4252 & (422378, 63381, 350094, 66949) & \approx 562965 & & new \\
\hline
4358 & (100212, 95919, 91496, 95921) & \approx 779392 &\mu_{\square} & new \\
     & (113251, 10894, 30563, 15074) & \approx 122594 &\mu_{\bigcirc} & new \\
\hline
4406 & (355473, 45564, 60271, 53068) & \approx 432399 & & new \\
\hline
4414 & (110846, 6721, 92198, 11873) & \approx 112464 & & new \\
\hline
4418 & (337601, 62681, 112753, 65441) & \approx 533793 &\mu_{\square} & new \\
     & (399547, 17732, 184381, 48658) & \approx 401248 &\mu_{\bigcirc} & new \\
\hline
4478 & (303719, 17780, 249983, 32590) & \approx 307636 & & new \\
\hline
4519 & (155665, 20255, 16057, 23369) & \approx 191605 &\mu_{\square} & JW \\
     & (166779, 571, 112551, 19193) & \approx 166779 &\mu_{\bigcirc} & JW +\\
\hline
4574 & (218107, 10033, 56333, 26627) & \approx 219215 & & new \\
\hline
4583 & (232822, 7771, 216312, 20217) & \approx 233152 & & JW \\
\hline
4630 & (489443, 83505, 63483, 88381) & \approx 729055 & & new \\
\hline
4643 & (101129, 9634, 73271, 12566) & \approx 109657 & & JW \\
\hline
4684 & (166861, 14052, 111837, 20338) & \approx 175923 & & ST + \\
\hline
4870 & (524118, 46841, 257242, 66375) & \approx 560794 & & ST + \\
\hline
4955 & (246607, 31000, 36819, 35946) & \approx 301603 & & new \\
\hline
4999 & (131429, 4656, 81439, 15054) & \approx 131687 & & JW + \\
\hline
\end{array}

If column "by..." is empty, then solution is smallest by both: $\mu_{\square}$ and $\mu_{\bigcirc}$.

Column "notes":

$ST$: found by Seiji Tomita (according to [this link](http://www.maroon.dti.ne.jp/fermat/dioph121e.html));

$JW$: found by Jaroslaw Wroblewski (according to [this link](http://www.maroon.dti.ne.jp/fermat/dioph121e.html));

$new$: new solution, a.f.a.i.k.;

$+$: confirm that result of Seiji Tomita database is the smallest (by $\mu_{\bigcirc}$), since doubt signs "???" are there;

$(small?)$: solution has $\max\{a,b,c,d\}<100\:000$.

Comment: I see the utility of the Notes. You are asking why the authors of the paper missed $3814,\,3818,\,3980$ when in fact it has solutions with $a,b,c,d<100000$. Hm.

Comment: Yes, indeed; number $3818$ has even $2$ solutions with $a,b,c,d<100000$: $$67219^4 - 39021^4 = 3818(8373^4 - 3637^4),$$
$$92852^4 - 3428^4 = 3818(13083^4 - 9957^4).$$

Answer (score 4):

I used a Maple program to first find the set $S$ of all positive integers $\le 10^{12}$ that can be written as the difference of two fourth powers (there are $649913$ of them),
then for successive integers $n$ find (if it exists) the least member of $S \cap (S/n$).  Thus for $n=2$ the result was $179727600$, corresponding to 
$179727600 = 116^4 - 34^4 = (139^4 - 61^4)/2$.
Hmm, this sequence belongs in the OEIS (it doesn't seem to be there yet).

There were $133$ cases up to $n=1000$ where $S \cap (nS)$ was empty, of which the first was $n=206$.  That doesn't say there is no solution for $n=206$, just that any solution will have $c^4 - a^4 > 10^{12}$.

Comment: Noam Elkies found that the smallest solution to $a^4+206b^4 = c^4+206d^4$ is $a,b,c,d = 3923, 1084, 4747, 506$.

Answer (score 3):

Equation $a^4+nb^4=c^4+nd^4$ has numerical solutions for all $n< 20000$   and is available on      Seiji Tomita website "Computational Number Theory" given below:

http://www.maroon.dti.ne.jp/fermat/eindex.html

Comment: @Oleg567: I didn't realize Tomita recently (just weeks ago!) updated his database and searched $n>1000$.

Answer (score 1):

Above equation given below:

$a^4+nb^4 = c^4+nd^4\tag{1}$

It has been shown that equation $(1)$ has numerical solutions for integer $n$ less than $20000$ and also $n$ rational for $n=\frac{b}a$ , for $100<a<200$ and $1<b<200$ ,

example for $(b,a) =(163,1)$ one solution is $(237,8,89,66)$. These solutions are given in latest article #254, on Seiji Tomita website  www.maroon.dti.ne.jp  If that table is extended $b>200$ than that it will fortify the conjecture that equation $(1)$ above could be true for $n$ both as an integer and a rational number.